# Create a list of instances and list of each instances variables

Tags: python, class, instance

I am trying to make a list of instances of one class, each with different attribute values, using this code:

```
lines_stripped = ['Name', 'Age', 'Score', 'John Whorfin', '52', '1.553', 'John Emdall', '35', '1.21', 'John Parker', '41', '1.987', 'John Gomez', '33', '1.305', 'John Yaya', '41', '1.411', 'John Gant', '39', '1.6821']
header = lines_stripped[0:3]
lines_stripped = lines_stripped[3:] 

class Lectroid():

    def __init__ (self, Name, Age, Score):

        self.name = Name
        self.age = Age
        self.score = Score


lectroidNames = range(0,6)  
#lectroidNames = lectroidNames.append('Lectroid')
i = 0
j = 1
k = 2
x = 0
while x < 6:
    lectroidNames[x] = Lectroid(lines_stripped[0], lines_stripped[1], lines_stripped[2]) #How can I not have constantly overriding lectroids
    i += 3
    j += 3
    k += 3
    x += 1
```

I had the intention of making each instance named after a number (hence `lectroidNames = range(0,6)`) but when I `print lectroidNames` I don't get a list of numbers or a list of instances. This is the output from `print lectroidNames`

```
[<__main__.Lectroid instance at 0x1085ad050>, <__main__.Lectroid instance at 0x1085ad098>, <__main__.Lectroid instance at 0x1085ad0e0>, <__main__.Lectroid instance at 0x1085ad128>, <__main__.Lectroid instance at 0x1085ad170>, <__main__.Lectroid instance at 0x1085ad1b8>]
```

I want to make a list of the scores from each instance. I tried to do this using `print lectroidNames.score` but I got this error message:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'score'`

Why do I receive this error message when I made each instance have the attribute score?
How can I gain the list of scores for each instance?

Comment: What exactly you want in the `lectroidNames` in the end ?

Comment: Do you want lectroidName to show its attributes when printed (so that you can print a list of lectroidName) or do you just want the list of scores from a list of lectroidName?

Comment: I want lectroidNames to be a list of the instances - I realise now this could have been better named. I want a different variable to contain the list of scores, called e.g. `lectroidScores`. I wanted `lectroidNames` to be a list from which I could look up other attributes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like,

```
$ cat make.py
lines_stripped = ['Name', 'Age', 'Score', 'John Whorfin', '52', '1.553', 'John Emdall', '35', '1.21', 'John Parker', '41', '1.987', 'John Gomez', '33', '1.305', 'John Yaya', '41', '1.411', 'John Gant', '39', '1.6821']
header = lines_stripped[0:3]
lines_stripped = lines_stripped[3:] 

class Lectroid():
        def __init__ (self, name, age, score):
                self.name = name
                self.age = age
                self.score = score


instances = []
data = iter(lines_stripped)
for _ in range(int(len(lines_stripped) / len(header))):
    name, age, score = [next(data) for _ in range(len(header)]
    instances.append(Lectroid(name, age, score))

for instance in instances:
    print(instance.name, instance.age, instance.score)
```

Output:

```
$ python make.py
('John Whorfin', '52', '1.553')
('John Emdall', '35', '1.21')
('John Parker', '41', '1.987')
('John Gomez', '33', '1.305')
('John Yaya', '41', '1.411')
('John Gant', '39', '1.6821')
```

Comment: There are so many ways to do this. It depends on where exactly you are getting the `lines_stripped` and the exact output you want

Comment: is there a way to acheive a similar result without using itertools or make.py? Also I am using python 2.7

Comment: Updated without using `itertools`, and this should work in `python2` too

Answer (score -1):

you can define an empty list then append:

```
lectroidNames =[]

i = 0
j = 1
k = 2
x = 0
while x < 6:
    lectroidNames.append(Lectroid(lines_stripped[i], lines_stripped[j], lines_stripped[k])) 
    i += 3
    j += 3
    k += 3
    x += 1
```

print output:

```
print(lectroidNames[0].name)
print(lectroidNames[1].name)
```

result:

```
John Whorfin
John Emdall
```

Comment: It does not answer the question.